# Improve speed of getpixel and putpixel

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Using PIL, I'm applying a rainbow filter to the given image using `getpixel` and `setpixel`. One issue, this method is very slow. It takes around 10 seconds to finish one image.

```py
def Rainbow(i):
    x = 1 - abs(((i / 60) % 2) - 1)
    i %= 360
    if (i >= 0   and i < 60 ): r,g,b = 1, x, 0
    if (i >= 60  and i < 120): r,g,b = x, 1, 0
    if (i >= 120 and i < 180): r,g,b = 0, 1, x
    if (i >= 180 and i < 240): r,g,b = 0, x, 1
    if (i >= 240 and i < 300): r,g,b = x, 0, 1
    if (i >= 300 and i < 360): r,g,b = 1, 0, x
    res = (int(r * 255), int(g * 255), int(b * 255))
    return res
def RainbowFilter(img):
    for x in range(img.size[0]):
        for y in range(img.size[1]):
            intensity = sum(img.getpixel((x, y)))
            img.putpixel((x, y), Rainbow(intensity + x + y))
    return img

im = Image.open('cat.jpg')
rainbow_im = RainbowFilter(im)
rainbow_im.save('rainbow_im.png')
```

[image: Input image]
[image: Result]
Can you help me improve my specific algorithm, using exclusively Numpy or Pillow features, to resolve the issue mentioned?

Comment: This is a XY problem. You should not use getpixel/setpixel because this is what make the processing inherently slow. You should use *buffered* accesses. The simplest solution is to use Numpy. And even with Numpy this will be quite slow as long as you use serial access over *vectorized* functions. CPython is a very slow *interpreter* (due to dynamic typing, object allocation, variable-sized integer, safe modulus, etc.) so it is not surprising such operation will be slow. Using a compiler mainly solve this problem. You can consider CPython has being a supertanker.

Comment: Your *Rainbow()* function could be made marginally more efficient however it seems most likely that you're at the mercy of the implementation of getpixel and putpixel. Maybe add some timing debug prints to see just how long they're taking

Comment: "buffered" is a horrible word for **direct** access. "buffered" implies **in**direct, because "buffered" says there's a "buffer" involved. get/putpixel include a bunch of extra work, hence aren't direct. -- python abuses the name "buffer".

Comment: I tested the OP's code with the supplied cat image and observed a runtime of just under 10 seconds - as reported. I then considered that the getpixel and putpixel processing could be separated into discrete processes - i.e., multiprocessing. Having done that the time comes down to 5.6s so still not great and maybe there's an even better way (I know virtually nothing about image processing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was intrigued by this and decided to have a go at optimising  the code from @I'mahdi.

My ideas were as follows:

- Create and zero the output image up-front and avoid writing the already zeroed elements in the main loops
- Only use parallelised `nb.prange()` for the *outer* loop since, if you have 12 CPU cores, that will already create 12 threads
- Avoid creating a new 3-element Numpy array in each iteration to assign to the RGB elements of the output array - just assign the two non-zero values directly
- Drastically reduce the number of tests in the `if` statements. The original code uses up to 12 tests to determine in which of the 6 sectors `i` falls. It will do all 12 if `i` is in the last sector. My code does it in 2-4 tests, more like a binary search.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

def Rainbow(i):
    x = 1 - abs(((i / 60) % 2) - 1)
    i %= 360
    if (i >= 0   and i < 60 ): r,g,b = 1, x, 0
    if (i >= 60  and i < 120): r,g,b = x, 1, 0
    if (i >= 120 and i < 180): r,g,b = 0, 1, x
    if (i >= 180 and i < 240): r,g,b = 0, x, 1
    if (i >= 240 and i < 300): r,g,b = x, 0, 1
    if (i >= 300 and i < 360): r,g,b = 1, 0, x
    res = (int(r * 255), int(g * 255), int(b * 255))
    return res

def RainbowFilter(img):
    for x in range(img.size[0]):
        for y in range(img.size[1]):
            intensity = sum(img.getpixel((x, y)))
            img.putpixel((x, y), Rainbow(intensity + x + y))
    return img

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def imahdi(img):    
    intensity = img.sum(axis=-1)
    row , col = img.shape[:2]
    for r in nb.prange(row):
        for c in nb.prange(col):
            i = (intensity[r,c] + r + c)
            x = 1 - abs(((i / 60) % 2) - 1)
            i %= 360
            res = np.zeros(3)
            if   (i >= 0   and i < 60 ): res = np.array([1, x, 0])
            elif (i >= 60  and i < 120): res = np.array([x, 1, 0])
            elif (i >= 120 and i < 180): res = np.array([0, 1, x])
            elif (i >= 180 and i < 240): res = np.array([0, x, 1])
            elif (i >= 240 and i < 300): res = np.array([x, 0, 1])
            elif (i >= 300 and i < 360): res = np.array([1, 0, x])
            img[r,c] = res * 255
    return img

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def mark(img):    
    intensity = img.sum(axis=-1)
    row , col = img.shape[:2]
    # Create zeroed result image
    res = np.zeros_like(img)
    for r in nb.prange(row):
        # Only make outer loop parallel else inner one will make more threads than cores
        for c in range(col):
            i = (intensity[r,c] + r + c)
            x = 1 - abs(((i / 60) % 2) - 1)
            x = int(x * 255)
            i %= 360
            # Split the problem space in half in one test - like binary search
            if i < 180:
               if i < 60:
                  # Don't create whole new array here 
                  # Don't assign zeroes, array is empty already
                  res[r,c,0] = 255
                  res[r,c,1] = x
               elif i < 120:
                  res[r,c,0] = x
                  res[r,c,1] = 255
               else:
                  res[r,c,1] = 255
                  res[r,c,2] = x
            else:
               if i < 240:
                  res[r,c,1] = x
                  res[r,c,2] = 255
               elif i < 300:
                  res[r,c,0] = x
                  res[r,c,2] = 255
               else:
                  res[r,c,0] = 255
                  res[r,c,2] = x
    return res

orig = Image.open('cat.jpg')
res  = RainbowFilter(orig)
res.save('result.png')

im  = np.asarray(orig)
res = imahdi(im)
Image.fromarray(res).save('imahdi.ppm')

res = mark(im)
Image.fromarray(res).save('mark.ppm')
```

Here are the timings:

```
In [17]: %timeit res = RainbowFilter(orig)                                      
11.7 s ± 80 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [18]: %timeit res = imahdi(im)                                               
1.52 s ± 4.81 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [13]: %timeit res=mark(im)                                                   
35.6 ms ± 928 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: I like how you split the problem space in half. I try to remember that! :) +1

Answer (score 2):

You can convert `image` to `NumPy.array` then use `numba` for improving speed like below:

```
from PIL import Image
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit(parallel=True)
def new_RainbowFilter(img):    
    intensity = img.sum(axis=-1)
    row , col = img.shape[:2]
    for r in nb.prange(row):
        for c in nb.prange(col):
            i = (intensity[r,c] + r + c)
            x = 1 - abs(((i / 60) % 2) - 1)
            i %= 360
            res = np.zeros(3)
            if   (i >= 0   and i < 60 ): res = np.array([1, x, 0])
            elif (i >= 60  and i < 120): res = np.array([x, 1, 0])
            elif (i >= 120 and i < 180): res = np.array([0, 1, x])
            elif (i >= 180 and i < 240): res = np.array([0, x, 1])
            elif (i >= 240 and i < 300): res = np.array([x, 0, 1])
            elif (i >= 300 and i < 360): res = np.array([1, 0, x])
            img[r,c] = res * 255
    return img


im = Image.open('cat.jpg')
img = np.asarray(im)
img = new_RainbowFilter(img)
im = Image.fromarray(img)
im.save('rainbow_im.png')
```