# Python numpy colormath error when using numba njit parallel process

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I've tried to use numba based on this post [Improve speed of getpixel and putpixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71724930/improve-speed-of-getpixel-and-putpixel).

But i'm encountering errors. I use colormath, PIL, numpy, numba

Untyped global name 'process': Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from colormath.color_conversions import convert_color
from colormath.color_objects import sRGBColor, LCHabColor 


@nb.jit(parallel=True)
def create_image(img_array, outputname):    
    img_array_c = np.copy(img_array)
    row , col = img_array_c.shape[:2]
    
    for r in nb.prange(row):
        for c in nb.prange(col):
            p = img_array_c[r,c]            
            p_mod = process(pixel)
            img_array_c[r,c] = p_mod
            
    return img_array_c


def process(p):

    rgb = sRGBColor(p[0]/255,p[1]/255,p[2]/255)
    lch = convert_color(rgb_color, LCHabColor) 
     
    c, h = func2(lch.lch_h, foo_array)    
    lch.lch_c *= c
    lch.lch_h += h
    
    c1 = lch.lch_c
    h1 = lch.lch_h * (np.pi/180)
    
    x = c1*np.cos(h1) + e #some constant
    y = c1*np.sin(h1) + f #some constant
    
    lch.lch_c = np.sqrt((x**2)+(y**2))
    angle = np.arctan2(y,x) * (180/np.pi)
    if angle<0:
        angle = 360+angle
    lch.lch_h = angle

    rgbnew = convert_color(lch_color, sRGBColor) 
    p_mod = (
        int(rgbnew.clamped_rgb_r * 255),
        int(rgbnew.clamped_rgb_g * 255),
        int(rgbnew.clamped_rgb_b * 255)
    )
    
    return p_mod
```

func2 I did not include but it uses a local function with some if else and numpy functions (np.argmin, np.abs)
convert_color is from colormath package. Is colormath having issues with numba?

Functions works without numba. I'm trying to do parallel processing to improve the run time of the image creation.

But i'm not sure which part is incompatible with numba code.

Comment: Numba doesn't support everything in python, see the [supported python features](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html) and the [supported numpy features](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html), to rewrite this in a numba compatible way, you'd need to implement `sRGBColor`, `convert_color` and it's returns attributes yourself. `func2` also has to either be wrapped with `numba.jit` or `numba.extending.register_jittable`

Comment: If you want a general-purpose JIT, then there is PyPy for that. Be aware that PyPy does not support all Python modules (though a significant part) and some rare modules require special manipulations (e.g. Numpy). Another alternative solution is to use Cython which support general-purpose codes and well supported (with no JIT overhead, simpler packaging, but Numpy is not rewritten as opposed to Numba so Numpy calls are still expensive in Cython).

Comment: Can you add the imports required to run this program? I can't figure out, for example, what `LCHabColor` is supposed to be.

Comment: @NickODell
Sorry I added the imports now in the post. The those are objects based on colormath package/import when using convert_color to change between color spaces/formats.

Comment: @Nin17
I see. Do you mean I won't be able to use the colormath package due to incompatibility with numba and I have to manually write the code to replace the functions/objects from colormath? I could do that.

Comment: Can you fix the variables which are undefined? It's hard to tell what `lch_color` is supposed to be, or what `func2()` does. I also don't follow why `lch.lch_c` is being converted into cartesian coordinates, then converted back into polar coordinates. That looks like a no-op, but I assume there's a purpose behind it?